# How to Create Multiple Dashoards using Plotly-Dash in Single Flask App?

Tags: python, flask, integration, plotly-dash

I now I can [integrate Python Dash with Flask](https://dash.plot.ly/integrating-dash), but is it possible to have more than one dashboards within single Flask application? The reason is that I want to have different dashboards for different User Groups, and I want each dashboard to scale independently from the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just create multiple dash instances. I'm not exactly sure what you mean with scale independently?

**Example**

Below is a minimal example of creating 2 dash instances. You can just add your figures and callbacks as you're used to.

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from flask import Flask

server = Flask(__name__)

# Set-up endpoint 1
app_1 = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server, url_base_pathname='/app1/')
app_1.layout = html.H1('App 1')

# Set-up endpoint 2
app_2 = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server, url_base_pathname='/app2/')
app_2.layout = html.H1('App 2')

# Run server
server.run()
```

Comment: I can't get this to work with a recent version of Dash: I'm just getting 404 errors for all urls.

Comment: Yes - but I've realised the problem is in my web-config - how the web server is configured.  It wasn't running wfastcgi for /app1/.  Obvious really - sorry.

Comment: Since Dash 2.0 this pattern is not longer supported. Each Dash instance now sets up global state in the dash module, so only one Dash instance should be run in a process at time, otherwise you'll find things breaking in weird and surprising ways.